# Given two Year + 1/3/5 integers, generate a vector of all Year + 1/3/5 integers between them (inclusive)

Tags: r

**My start on an example**:

```
yr_min <- 20181
yr_max <- 20195

as.numeric(paste0(rep(
  seq(as.numeric(substr(yr_min, 1, 4)), 
      as.numeric(substr(yr_max, 1, 4))), 
  each = 3),
  c(1, 3, 5)))

[1] 20181 20183 20185 20191 20193 20195
```

**What is wrong with the above code**? It will not generalize beyond situations where `yr_min` ends in a `1` and `yr_max` ends in a `5`.

For example:

```
yr_min <- 20183
yr_max <- 20193

as.numeric(paste0(rep(
  seq(as.numeric(substr(yr_min, 1, 4)), 
      as.numeric(substr(yr_max, 1, 4))), 
  each = 3),
  c(1, 3, 5)))

[1] 20181 20183 20185 20191 20193 20195
```

The desired output is

```
[1] 20183 20185 20191 20193
```

Comment: It seems easier to just generate the sequence of base decades 20180, 20190... and add the offsets 1,3,5 yourself. Or else generate the entire sequence of years `seq(yr_min, yr_max)` and `Filter()` out anything which isn't 1,3,5 modulo 10.

Comment: Oh, was this supposed to represent year-month like 2018 Jan, Mar, May, 2019 Jan, Mar, May? It would break on two-digit months, as @TimBiegeleisen suggests. (You didn't tell us so I just coded what you originally asked for)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Generate the entire sequence of years then `Filter()` out anything which isn't 1,3,5 modulo 10.

```
rem_135_mod10 <- function(x) { (x %% 10) %in% c(1,3,5) }

Filter(rem_135_mod10, seq(yr_min, yr_max))
# 20181 20183 20185 20191 20193 20195
```

- This is functional programming in R with the constructs [Filter(), Map(), Reduce()...](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html))
- as the others say, for these specific remainders 1,3,5, you can exploit that you only need step 2: `seq(yr_min, yr_max, by=2)`

or 2) generate the sequence of base decades 20180, 20190... and add the offsets 1,3,5 yourself. Same difference.

Comment: Before someone decides to tell me that I'm wrong for not choosing the highest-voted answer, I want to say that I'm actually really happy with this answer. It's a really clever use of modular arithmetic, and for collaboration, it is the easiest to read and modify.

Comment: @Clarinetist: Thanks. More about functional programming in R: [`Filter(), Map(), Reduce()...`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html)

Comment: As the others say, you can exploit that you only need step 2: `seq(yr_min, yr_max, by=2)`

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using bona fide dates in your calculation.  This allows us to take advantage of base R's `seq` function:

```
x <- seq(as.Date("2018/3/1"), as.Date("2019/3/1"), by="month")
x[format(x, "%m") %in% c("01", "03", "05")]

[1] "2018-03-01" "2018-05-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-03-01"
```

If you really want the exact format you have, you can easily do that with another call to `format`:

```
y <- x[format(x, "%m") %in% c("01", "03", "05")]
format(y, "%Y%m")

[1] "201803" "201805" "201901" "201903"
```

Or, for your *exact* output:

```
sub("(?<=\\d{4}).", "", format(y, "%Y%m"), perl=TRUE)

[1] "20183" "20185" "20191" "20193"
```

Comment: This is -almost- perfect, but I cannot have the extra zero in there - i.e., the output needs to be `20183`, `20185`, etc.

Comment: @Clarinetist I gave you an update, but I think that two digits is actually more appropriate, because perhaps at a later date you could have October through December, which are two digit months.

Comment: I do not set any of the formatting that has been laid out here (this is for a SQL query). These numbers do not represent months, but rather, partitions of the year into three segments. Mathematically, the problem is laid out in the original question.

Comment: I have an interest in SQL, and maybe you should add some details about that to your question.  Note that most SQL databases have the ability to generate dates, so you might not even need R.

Comment: I don't have access to a program like SQL Developer or SQL Server Management Studio in this situation for accessing these particular data, otherwise I would use it.

Answer (score 0):

predefined data:

```
end_vec <- c(1, 3, 5)
yr_min  <- 20183
yr_max  <- 20193
```

code:

```
ans<-
c(
sapply(c(yr_min, yr_max), function(x) {n<-nchar(x);as.numeric(paste0(substr(x,1,n-1),end_vec))})
)

ans[dplyr::between(ans, yr_min, yr_max)]
```

result:

```
# [1] 20183 20185 20191 20193
```